# Random effect model in r

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'd like to know the appropriate command to run a random-effect model under the software R.

I tried :

```
library(plm)
Model=plm(df$IndVar ~ df$densite + df$sexe + df$age_cat + df$production, data=df, index=c("village"), model="random")
```

But I got this answer :

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(e1, e2) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I also tried :

```
library(nlme)            
Model=lme(df$IndVar ~ df$densite + df$sexe + df$age_cat + df$production, random=~1|village)
```

And I got :

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'IndVar' not found
```

What to do ? Need your help.

Comment: Please show your data as `dput(df)` after editing the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Just type `dput(df)` in R then copy and paste the output here by clicking the edit option. Visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: for `lme` dont use `data$variable` use the `data=` argument. So try `Model=lme(IndVar ~ densite + sexe + age_cat + production, data=df,random=~1|village)`

Comment: The code doesn't work

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean ... did you get an error?

Comment: Error : type (list) incorrect pour la variable 'df'

Comment: okay thanks. Can you show exactly what code you used to get that please (as my code ^^ didn't have a variable df)